# how to get model from KF Containerized Python Component into Vertex AI model registry properly

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

if custom model training happens in Containerized Python Component, producing model file and metrics, what is the proper way of uploading the model and its metrics into Vertex AI so that they are available via Vertex AI UI?

Google has changed almost everything in Vertex AI V2 in case to accomodate for changes in Kubeflow V2, but is is largely undocumented and there are no clear examples around.

Comment: Hi @Maxim Volgin , Can you check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-registry/import-model), it's mentioned that after you import your model, it is visible in the Vertex AI Model Registry. From there, you can deploy your imported model to an endpoint and run predictions. Is this helpful ?